Why is a top-level code executed twice in NodeJs?
I am modifying a project where a file contains some infrastructure variables. I executed code with side effects at the top level, but found that the side effects were repeatedly triggered during runtime.
So I tried adding debugging code to it:

lib/utils/ofetch.ts

import { createFetch } from 'ofetch';
import { config } from '@/config';
import logger from '@/utils/logger';

debugger; // add to here
console.log('expect',new Error().stack) // add to here

const rofetch = createFetch().create({
...

Then debugging was carried out, and the stack information obtained is as follows:
expect Error
    at <anonymous> (/Users/bugyaluwang/project/RSSHub/lib/utils/ofetch.ts:6:22)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:268:25)
    at async onImport.tracePromise.__proto__ (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:543:26)
    at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:116:5)
expect Error
    at logger (/Users/bugyaluwang/project/RSSHub/lib/utils/ofetch.ts:6:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bugyaluwang/project/RSSHub/lib/utils/ofetch.ts:34:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
    at Object.transformer (/Users/bugyaluwang/project/RSSHub/node_modules/.pnpm/tsx@4.19.1/node_modules/tsx/dist/register-DpmFHar1.cjs:2:1186)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:141:16)
    at ofetch (/Users/bugyaluwang/project/RSSHub/lib/utils/got.ts:2:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bugyaluwang/project/RSSHub/lib/utils/got.ts:86:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
    at Object.transformer (/Users/bugyaluwang/project/RSSHub/node_modules/.pnpm/tsx@4.19.1/node_modules/tsx/dist/register-DpmFHar1.cjs:2:1186)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)

I saw things related to ESM and CommonJS in it, but I don't quite know the next direction for troubleshooting.
In addition to these pieces of information, there are also some other pieces of information:

Run through tsx (You can clone this repository and run pnpm dev to start)
node: v22.10.0
pnpm: v9.12.1

I have tried:

Check for circular references. I did see some circular dependencies in places where there are references to ofetch.ts (config.ts \ logger.ts). But after trying to resolve it, it didn't work.
I guess it's a problem with tsx, but the modification is invalid.
I tried to understand the logic of repeated runs through counting and found that it seems to be independent context.
Suspected it was related to @hono/node-server, but did not put it into practice because I am not very familiar with it.

Overall, I hope to avoid the issue of duplicate runs in the ofetch.ts file and also hope to understand the specific reasons.

The problem has been identified as the flaws of the TSX composite CJS and dynamic import https://github.com/privatenumber/tsx/issues/499

"The problem has been identified as the flaws of the TSX composite CJS and dynamic import github.com/privatenumber/tsx/issues/499" - consider posting a self-answer, this looks like a piece of info that may be valuable to other readers. I wasn't aware of this tsx problem myself
